# SSL Server doesn't run

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, server

I'm trying to set up a simple socket server and test it to see if it works, however everytime I try to run it in cmd, it just gets stuck and nothing happens, so I have to control C it every time. It's frustrating because I don't get any error messages that I could use to google.

I already have 1 certificate entry in the MySrvKeystore.

Here's the code, it compiles just fine but doesn't run.

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.net.ssl.*;
 import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 import java.security.KeyStore;


public class SSLServerWithAuth{

public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 6060;

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        char[] passphrase = "changeit".toCharArray();

        //Need to set up TrustManager/TrustStore, and MessageDigest? Maybe.
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("mySrvKeystore.jks"), passphrase);

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(6060);
            SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ss.accept();

            ss.setNeedClientAuth(true);


        //  if(/** Name**/.equals("-a")) {

                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [16*1024];
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

                int current = bytesRead;

                do {
                    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                    if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                } while(bytesRead > -1);

                bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
                bos.flush();
                s.close();
        //  }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            }



    }
```

}

Comment: it's likely "stuck" in the `while` loop, you could use `is.available()` to check if the read could be done without blocking.

Comment: also ofcourse you need some client to connect to your server, otherwise it would just sit in the `accept()` waiting for someone to connect. To quickly test you could use `telnet localhost 6060`

Comment: @geert3 I took out while loop, but it still doesn't run at all, I do "java SSLServerWithAuth" in cmd and it just gets stuck, while compiling just fine.

Comment: see also second comment. Finally using some debugger (Eclipse?) you could single-step your program which would be helpful as you would immediately see where it was stuck.

Comment: I think the problem was that I thought I needed to successfully run the Server first, and then run the client, not both at the same time. So you were right, it was probably stuck on accept(). Once I ran the client, it got out of the process instead of getting stuck, and I finally got the error messages. Thanks a lot. @geert3